# Delete duplicate rows in a table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

**What will be the query for this result in oracle 11g**

i have a table caller product_table.in my product_table i have no primary key and i have these records

```
pid  pname   pprice
===  =====   ======
101   aaa      343
101   aaa      343
101   aaa      343
101   aaa      343
```

i want a query which will delete all the duplicate values except one record

means after executing that query i need this result

```
pid  pname   pprice
===  =====   ======
101   aaa      343
```

**Can it be possible with sql query or sub query without using any function or procedure logic ??**

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there a index of some type on this table?

Comment: Maybe try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+delete+duplicates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can do this using `rowid` and a subquery:

```
delete from product_table
    where rowid not in (select min(rowid)
                        from product_table
                        group by pid, pname, pprice
                       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well sir Gordon Linoff's answer is correct but this can be also achieved using **self join**

```
delete from product_table p1
  where rowid not in
  (select max(rowid) from product_table p2
  where p1.pid = p2.pid );
```